# Loading data into HTML Tables using AJAX JavaScript don't work

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have data stored in json file, like this:

```
[
["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"],
["cell4", "cell5", "cell6"]
...
]
```

I want to convert json data to html table, so I created below code (html structure + loading the data separately from a dedicated json data-file located in the same directory **"rows.json"**):

```
<body>
    <table id="tab">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>column_1</th>
                <th>column_2</th>
                <th>column_3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
        const TabBody = document.querySelector("#tab > tbody") 
        function loadData() {
            const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("get", "rows.json");
            request.onload = () => {
                try {
                    const json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    populateTable(json);
                    }  catch (e) {
                        console.warn("error");
                    }   
                };
                
            request.send();
        }
        function populateTable(json){
            
            while(TabBody.firstChild){TabBody.removeChild(TabBody.firstChild);}

            json.forEach((row) => { 
                const tr = document.createElement("tr");

                row.forEach((cell) => {
                    const td = document.createElement("td");
                    td.textContent = cell;
                    tr.appendChild(td);})
                
                TabBody.appendChild(tr);
            })            
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

The code don't work, and the table body is not loaded shown. Maybe the code is not correct, or not efficient and there is better ways to do it..

Comment: What doesn t work? what errors do you get? how can someone reproduce the problem? Nothing is clear about the question

Comment: the table can't be shown on the browser, my question is I want to convert json data to html table

Comment: Might be a simple case of needing to call `loadData();` right before the closing `</script>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `populateTable` function seems correct, I copied it over to a snippet and it works fine.

- Do you get the correct data from the `XMLHttpRequest`?
- Where do you call the `loadData` function? Did you forget to call it?

```js
const data = [
  ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3"],
  ["cell4", "cell5", "cell6"]
]

const TabBody = document.querySelector("#tab > tbody");

function populateTable(json) {

  while (TabBody.firstChild) {
    TabBody.removeChild(TabBody.firstChild);
  }

  json.forEach((row) => {
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");

    row.forEach((cell) => {
      const td = document.createElement("td");
      td.textContent = cell;
      tr.appendChild(td);
    })

    TabBody.appendChild(tr);
  })
}

populateTable(data);
```

```html
<table id="tab">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>column_1</th>
      <th>column_2</th>
      <th>column_3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tabulator in this case.
you can load json data inside and it gives you many features and ability to style the table.

here you can read about how to insert data from ajax request:
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/data#ajax

if you want to make the request and input the response in the table,
can do this after you have a response from your code:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
                height: '70%', // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
                data: res.json, //assign data to table, json response
                layout: "fitDataFill", //fit columns to width of data
                pagination: "local",
                paginationSize: 10,
                paginationSizeSelector: [5, 10, 15, 20],
                movableColumns: true,
                selectable: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        formatter: "buttonCross", align: "center", title: "del", headerSort: false, cellClick: function (e, cell) {
                            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?'))
                                cell.getRow().delete();
                            console.log(rowJson = cell.getRow().getData())
                        }
                    },
                    { title: "id", field: "id", sorter: "number" },
                    { title: "Name", field: "name", sorter: 'string' },
                    { title: "phone", field: "phone", sorter: "number" },
                    { title: "email", field: "email", sorter: 'string' },
                    { title: "location", field: "location", sorter: 'string' },
                    { title: "price/night", field: "price", sorter: 'number' },
                    { title: "number of rooms", field: "roomsnumber", sorter: 'number' },
                    { title: "capacity", field: "capacity", sorter: 'number' },
                    { title: "available", field: "available", sorter: 'string' },
                    { title: "start time", field: "startTime", sorter: 'string' },
                    { title: "date", field: "date", sorter: "date", },
                ]
                
            });
```

it's very easy to use and there are many features..